# перебор двумерного массива в функции

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Работаю с функциями, не получается перебрать двумерный массив различными числами, с одномерными массивами отлично получается

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
void random(const int STR, const int ELEM, int arr[]){
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < STR; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < ELEM; j++)
      {
         arr[j] = rand() % 3;
         cout<<arr[i][j]<<endl;
      }    
   }
};
int main(){
   const int STR = 2;
   const int ELEM = 3;
   int arr[STR][ELEM];
   random(STR, ELEM, arr);
}
```

Comment: А ещё `arr[j] = rand() % 3;` у вас же двумерный массив, так и пишите `arr[i][j] = rand() % 3;`.

Comment: Давно уже не двадцатый век, и  наши компиляторы и компьютеры тоже не оттуда.   Если быстродействие так критично, или  сам код так тривиален,  и вы пытаетесь передавать их в функцию, то много проще  _  шаблон функции, а еще проще и безопаснее использовать  хороший  матричный класс. или просто стандартные контейнеры.

Comment: По поводу массивов  информации  довольно достаточно и в этом сайте и в многих других. Сколько можно про них спрашивать? По эти соображениям, я голосую за закрытие подобных вопросов.